# replacing values with zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, I want to replace whole values to zeros except some range of index.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I tried

```
Import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
print(data)
```

expected output

```
0
0
3
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the array with a for loop and check if the traversed element is in a list of desired selected values:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
nums = [3]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in nums:
        pass
    else:
        a[i] = 0
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[0 0 3 0 0]
```

Comment: instead of nums = [3] if i want range of values to be kept others to be zero this dosnot work,........ for example nums=[2:4]

Comment: @viraj-moil For a range, `nums` should be `nums = list(range(2, 5))`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @viraj-moil The code runs fine, please check the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you're working with a numpy array, use vectorial methods.

Here `isin` to form a boolean mask for replacement:

```
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
l = [3]

data[~np.isin(data, l)] = 0

data
# array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Segmentation fault

Comment: i need to do it for number of values such as l=[20:34]

Comment: There is something wrong with your python/numpy installation. We can't help you until you fix that

Comment: Then `data[~np.isin(data, np.r_[20:34+1])] = 0`

Comment: it doesnot work all values gets zeros

Comment: You need to give more details, to provide a fully reproducible example. Trying on the provided data with `data[~np.isin(data, np.r_[2:3+1])] = 0`, I get `array([0., 2., 3., 0., 0.])` as expected.